# JS: Don't add value to map on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that I need to convert into an array. This is the object:

```
const dogCounts: {
    maltese: 4,
    poodle: 2,
    labrador: 10,
    corso: 0
}
```

And I send it to a component thru props and I have a useMemo hook to convert it into a structure like this:  `[ [maltese, 4], [poodle, 2], ... ]`

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const z = Object.keys(dogCounts || {})?.map(i => {
        if (dogCounts[i] === 0) return; // Don't add it to map and skip it

        return [i, dogCounts[i]]
    })
}, [dogCounts])
```

When the number is zero I don't want to add it to the formatDogCounts variable. What I put above doesn't fit to eslints rules. `Arrow function expected no return value.eslintconsistent-return`.

Also I put that {} in the object.keys for the case when the counts haven't loaded yet is there a cleaner way to null check that?

Comment: `map` includes every item, nevertheless the return value. Use `filter` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` doesn't filter out values; doing a simple `return;` in `map` makes the corresponding entry in the result array `undefined`. If you want to do that, you'll need to `filter` first, or build the array another way (such as a simple loop).

Here's the `filter` approach:

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const z = Object.keys(dogCounts || {})?
                .filter(name => dogCounts[name] !== 0)
                .map(name => [name, dogCounts[i]]);
}, [dogCounts]);
```

Note that `Object.entries` provides the very `[name, value]` pairs you want, so you could avoid `map`, and there's no reason for the conditional chaining operator as neither `Object.keys` nor `Object.entries` ever returns `undefined` or `null`:

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const z = Object.entries(dogCounts || {})
                .filter(([, value]) => value !== 0);
}, [dogCounts]);
```

Note the `,` prior to `value` in the `[, value]` destructuring pattern so we're grabbing the second array entry (the value), not the first (the name).

We can also avoid the calls to `Object.entries` and `filter` entirely when there is no `dogCounts`:

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const z = dogCounts
        ? Object.entries(dogCounts).filter(([, value]) => value !== 0)
        : [];
}, [dogCounts]);
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> The entries solution worked really well for me! Is there a way now to return an object instead of an array with total dog counts and then an array of items? Ex: formatDogCounts: { totalDogs: 30, items: [...] }

Sure. If there will only ever be a reasonable number of dogs (fewer than hundreds of thousands), I'd just do it as a separate operation at the end:

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const items = dogCounts
        ? Object.entries(dogCounts).filter(([, value]) => value !== 0)
        : [];
    return {
        totalDogs: items.reduce((sum, [, value]) => sum + value, 0),
        items,
    };
}, [dogCounts]);
```

*(A straight sum is the only ad hoc use of `reduce` I'll do, and even then I don't much care for it.)*

Or you could make your `filter` callback slightly impure and count them as you go:

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    let totalDogs = 0;
    const items = dogCounts
        ? Object.entries(dogCounts).filter(([, value]) => {
            totalDogs += value;
            return value !== 0;
        })
        : [];
    return {
        totalDogs,
        items,
    };
}, [dogCounts]);
```

Comment: The entries solution worked really well for me! Is there a way now to return an object instead of an array with total dog counts and then an array of items? Ex: formatDogCounts: { totalDogs: 30, items: [...] }

Comment: @ousmane784 - Sure, I've shown doing that. Happy coding!

Comment: Awsome, in terms of speed would the filters callback be faster because the reduce method would need to loop thru the array again?

Comment: @ousmane784 - Probably, but you'd have to be dealing with hundreds of thousands entries in the array (or more) for it to matter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform a `map` and `filter` operation together, you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), returning an empty array to skip an element.

```
const formatDogCounts = useMemo(() => {
    const z = Object.keys(dogCounts || {})?.flatMap(i => {
      if(dogCounts[i] === 0) return []; // Dont add it to map and skip it

      return [[i, dogCounts[i]]];
    })
  }, [dogCounts])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter using a `map` which isn't possible. Map will return the same amount of values as you put in. You can do a `foreach` or you can do a combination of `map` and `filter` to get the expected results.

**Foreach**

```
const z = []

Object.keys(dogCounts).forEach((key) => {
  if(dogCounts[key]) {
    // if the value is truthy push the structure to the array. 
    z.push([key, dogCounts[key]]); 
  }
}
```

**Map/Filter**

```
const z = Object.keys(dogCount)
  .map((key) => [key, dogCount[key]) // map to restructure object.keys
  .filter(([key, value]) => value); // filter to remove falsey values (0, null, undefined)
```